# unknown property 'GMS_VERSION'

Tags: android, phonegap-cli

Following error display when try to create apk for phonegap:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'www_android'.
>   Could not get unknown property 'GMS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here using Ionic. You can get it to build by modifying "../platforms/android/project.properties" and changing

[image]

to

[image]